# Boolean doesn't break for statement

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, boolean, break

I am new to the forum AND new to programming.
I apologize in advance if my questions are really basic but I am really new to this and I had to learn a lot in a really short time, so I may miss a couple of concepts.

On to my question,
I have a method who is supposed to check if a matrix still have spaces available and stop if it finds one.

The matrix has been initialized like this (I know it could be in one line, but the matrix is created within the constructor of an object)

```
protected char[][] matJeu = null;
matJeu = new char[10][10];
```

It has then been filled with spaces like this ' ' with a for statement and it works just fine

Here is the method

```
public boolean checkIfFull()
{
    boolean full = true;
    for (int i=0;i<matJeu.length || !full;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<matJeu[i].length || !full ;j++)
        {
            if(matJeu[i][j]==' '){
                full = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return full;
}
```

The problem is that when the full boolean turns to false, the for loops doesn't break and ends up by causing an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. If the matrix is full, it simply returns true. So I may be missing the correct way to cause a boolean to break a for loop.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why not replace `full = false` with `return false`?

Comment: @BJ Myers  That did work. Thanks a lot, but I would still like to know how I can break a for statement in that kind of situation ? Is this the only way if I want to cancel a for statement with a boolean ?

Comment: remove  `!full` in `for` loop and replace `full = false;` with `return false;`

Comment: @Jerry06 Yes, that does work, thanks for the answer. But still, I would like to know what in this current code doesn't work. Let's say that for one reason or another, I'd like to break a for statement outside of a method or something like that. And I have to break the for statement with a boolean.
How can the program evaluate !full as true ?

Comment: `!true == false`, and likewise, `!false == true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional part of the loop will cause the loop to continue as long as it returns `true`.

As soon as `full=false` is hit, then `!full==true`, and the conditional statement will always evaluate to `true` (`anything || true == true`), essentially putting you in an infinite loop with your current code.

To break your for loop, you need the conditional part to evaluate to `false`.

I'm not sure what you intend your loops to do, as stopping at the first space character doesn't seem like what you want based on the previous paragraph.

Comment: Well. Isn't !full the same as full == false ? If so, how can this be evaluated as true ?

Comment: `full==false` (Or equivalently `!full`) evaluates to `true` if `full` *is* `false`.

Comment: Well this matrix is supposed to be filled with Spaces (for neutral) the R character for player 1 and the B character for player 2. This method is supposed to check if there's any space left in the grid, because if there is not, then that game is a tie. And I don't want the method to scan the entire grid EVEN after finding a space.

Comment: Ah - you didn't mention anything about other characters in the matrix in your question. Just focus on when your condition should evaluate to true (loop should continue), and when it should evaluate to false (loop should stop). Try to read things like `!full` as "not full", and remember the logic rules I've outlined in various other comments.

Comment: I understand, and as far as I'm concerned you answered my question. But I'd still like to know how I could achieve such a result. I mean, I tough a for statement would be broken if ONE of the two conditions were true. Which is kind of the situation right now, The 'full' boolean turns to false, so the !full statement is then evaluated as true since full is false. Then why doesn't the for stops ?

Comment: @JimmyRobitaille - the condition `!full` made one of the condition `false`. But there isn't only that condition in the for loop. You have 2 conditions in the loop. So it evaluates to `condition1 || false`. Had it been `AND` instead of `OR`, the false condition will make the whole condition false thereby breaking the loop.

Comment: @JimmyRobitaille - In summary, if you need both conditions to be false you'll use `condition1 || condition2` which will only be false if both conditions are false. If you need either conditions to be false to make the whole expression false use `condition1 && condition2`.

Comment: @alvits Ah, now I get it. All right, well that's that, I wish I could put more than one people as the answers since all of you guys helped me a lot. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the *or* condition on your for loops.

```
for (int i=0;i<matJeu.length || !full;i++)
```

Here, the loop is going to continue executing so long as *at least one*  of the conditions is true.

Because `i<mathJeu.length` is still true, the loop keeps executing, regardless of whether `full` is `true` or `false`.

Instead - what you want is an *and* condition.

```
for (int i=0;i<matJeu.length && full;i++)
```

This will tell it 'keep looping so long as it's below the array length AND we've detected it's still full'.

Comment: This has the same problem as Skip's answer: Your logic is not correct - the loop won't even start in this case since `full==true`, meaning `!full` evaluates to false, and `anything && false` is false.

Comment: @Chris Yip - I just noticed that, dealing with that now.